# Right click could not be performed in IE using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to perform right click on IE11 selenium c#. I'm using 2 of the below approaches, but none of them trigger the right click. Although no error was received, but also right click was not performed to open the context menu. 
Please note my selenium webdriver & IE Webdriver versions are both 3.8.

**Approach 1:**

```
 string script = "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"
                    + "var RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE = 2;"
                    + "evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, " +
                    " false, false, false, RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE, null);"
                    + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);"; 
       IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)SmokeTestSuite.browser;
       js.ExecuteScript(script, webElement);
```

**Approach 2:**

```
Actions builder = new Actions(SmokeTestSuite.browser);
builder.MoveToElement(objectToBeClicked);
builder.ContextClick(objectToBeClicked).Build().Perform();
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="scrollHeader" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 17px;">
    <div class="tree-grid2">
        <div class="tree-grid2-row">
            <div class="tree-grid2-cell" title="Coaching Notes" style="min-width: 34px; max-width: 34px;">
                <div>
                    <div class="coaching-note-icon">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**InternetExplorerOptions are:** EnsureCleanSession = true,IgnoreZoomLevel = true,IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true, EnableNativeEvents = false,EnablePersistentHover = false,RequireWindowFocus = true, PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager

Comment: Right click was performed using 1. //div[@class='scrollHeader'] 2. //div[@class='tree-grid2'] and even 3. //div[@title='Coaching Notes']. All of them failed to work. Note that Element was found successfully, but just that right click event is not performed

Comment: Is it working in other browsers?

Comment: Yes, its working in Chrome using Selenium's Actions class code.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different stable version of IE driver which is dedicated to your IE version.